# Win32Exception in Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, build, unity-game-engine

[image]I have developed a sample android application in unity3d.I got one unexpected error while taking build that is **Win32Exception** .I didn't get any idea about this error.So Please find the error message below.Please help me.

I suffer from the below error:

```
  Win32Exception: ApplicationName='python', CommandLine='Assets/Kamcord/Editor/KamcordAndroidProjectProcessor.pyc "C:/Users/Cube5/Desktop/VRecord1.apk" "KamcordAndroid"', CurrentDirectory=''
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
KamcordPostprocessScript.OnPostprocessBuild (BuildTarget target, System.String pathToBuildProject) (at Assets/Kamcord/Editor/KamcordPostprocessScript.cs:48)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

and How to run the **Assets/Kamcord/Editor/KamcordAndroidProjectProcessor.pyc** in Python Command line.and i tried but it came name error that is the above image screen shot.so how to solve this?

Comment: Have you installed python on your pc ? can you run pyc command from command line ?

Comment: I am not Installed python.

Comment: I Installed now and run also.next what i can do?.@Ahmed

Comment: now try to run it again.

Comment: I given "Assets/Kamcord/Editor/KamcordAndroidProjectProcessor.pyc" as console but it came asset is not found.so how to solve this.@Ahmed

Comment: Have you installed this Kamcord plugin ? http://www.kamcord.com/developers/download/

Comment: yes installed Kamcord plugin.@Ahmed

Comment: Confirm that it is android version check the link i post, because if its saying not found then probably it is not installed correctly.

Comment: Kamcord installation was good.I think the problem is python.Can you  please tell me once After running the python what i can do? Because I am using the python is 1 st time.@Ahmed

Comment: you can check if python is installed correctly by running 'python' (without ') in command line.

Comment: yes its running.@Ahmed

Comment: Please post the exact error now and update and your question.

Comment: I updataed please check once.@Ahmed

Comment: Sorry I mean run unity again and post the error you are getting there,

Comment: Oh Sorry now i updated please check once.@Ahmed.

Comment: You take a screenshot of the error in unity not in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you dont have python installed, you can install it from http://www.python.org/getit/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I did come across this error in my project. The error is telling you that it cannot find the python.exe to run the script file.

Here is an example:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"C:\Users\someuser\Documents\PythonVenvs\venv\Scripts\python.exe";
```

Hope this helps.